# Cloud 9 and meteor apps

Tags: meteor, hybrid-mobile-app, cloud9-ide

Can I Build a meteor android app in cloud 9.

```
meteor add-platform android
```

Because Im running on windows or should I install linux and run

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

and build it locally.

Comment: Have you tried running it on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build android app on Windows you need to be using the meteor 1.3 release beta which you can install by running `meteor update --release 1.3-cordova-beta.5` in your project folder - [Details on this release](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6050)

Prior to 1.3 you will need to build the app on a linux machine

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Meteor app on Cloud9 using any version of Meteor. See [Meteor on Cloud9](https://docs.c9.io/docs/meteor).